# Mixpanel object php

Tags: php, object

Two part question: After calling the Mixpanel api I am returned something like this

```
stdClass Object ( 
    [legend_size] => 1 
    [data] => stdClass Object ( 
        [series] => Array ( 
            [0] => 2011-04-06 
            [1] => 2011-04-07 ) 
        [values] => stdClass Object ( 
            [Login loaded] => stdClass Object ( 
                [2011-04-06] => 1 
                [2011-04-07] => 1 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

Let's say I stored this in $data

If I do

```
$value = $data->data->values->Login loaded
```

I get an error because of the space in between Login and loaded. How do I escape this space?

Second question

Once I get the above figured out, can I do something like

```
$value = $data->data->values->Login->$date
```

where

```
$date = '2011-05-06'
```

? Can I stick in a variable in place of a class name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Question: `$value = $data->data->values->{'Login loaded'}` or:

```
$key = 'Login loaded';
$value = $data->data->values->$key
```

Second Question: Yes

You can pretty much use anything as a variable name (including object members) if you use variable variables, `{}` variable wrappers, and the like.

E.g.:

```
$this->$foo
${'a weird variable name'}
$object->$something->{'very weird'}
$foo = 'bar';  $$foo = 3; // $bar = 3 now.
```

EDIT: While we're at it, **this** is never valid:

```
$foo = new Foo;
$foo::bar(); // syntax error
```

You can't access the static properties of a class instance stored in a variable.  However, you could do something like:

```
$foo = new Foo;
call_user_func(get_class($foo) . '::bar');
```